# Android Alarm Manager not firing, trying to send Notification

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I'm trying to set up a one-time alarm that will wake up my app and then deliver a notification to the user.

I'm setting the alarm for 1 minute in the future, but my broadcast receiver is never called.

This is how I'm scheduling the `AlarmManager` and building the `Notification`:

```
private void scheduleNotification(Date notificationdate) {
    Log.d("PSBMF", "scheduling notification at "+notificationdate);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+AppController.statewidephone));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);

    String notificationmessage = "Test Message";
    String channelid = "Channel Id";
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity(), channelid)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning_black_36dp)
            .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
            .setContentText("Notification Content")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Notification Content"))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            ;

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mActivity, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long notificationTimeInMillis = notificationdate.getTime();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, notificationTimeInMillis, pendingAlarmIntent);

}
```

My `NotificationPublisher.class` looks like this:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("NP", "NOTIFICATION RECEIVED: "+context);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

and I've registered my `NotificationPublisher/BroadcastReceiver` by putting this inside the `<application/>` tag of my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher"/>
```

What else am I missing? Why won't my Alarm get triggered and call the `onReceive` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out my problem:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, notificationTimeInMillis, pendingAlarmIntent);
```

should be

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notificationTimeInMillis, pendingAlarmIntent);
```

Comment: @ADM I am required to wait several days before accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Feel link this has to do with the changes to [broadcast receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts).

Registering receivers in the manifest will no longer work based on:

> Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

The note above was copied from the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

try to register your broadcast dynamically

```
NotificationPublisher myBroadcastReceiver = new NotificationPublisher();// Register the broadcast
registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And change this
`alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,notificationTimeInMillis, pendingAlarmIntent);`

 to

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,notificationTimeInMillis, pendingAlarmIntent);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to set a repeating alarm. I explicitly said I was trying to set a one-time alarm.

Comment: okay you did not mention that, try to register broadcast as I mentioned above

Comment: It was literally the first thing I wrote in the post: "I'm trying to set up a one-time alarm..."

Comment: I am sorry my bad